# Couldn't able tag an SVN in Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, svn

I am trying to tag an svn in a jenkins job but I am getting following error.I am using subversion V_2.4.3 and SVN Tag version 1.18. svn/svnsever/...../...
does not exist in revision 112,374

```
ERROR: Subversion copy failed.
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E160013

at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCopyDriver.copyReposToRepos(SVNCopyDriver.java:263)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCopyDriver.setupCopy(SVNCopyDriver.java:627)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNCopyClient16.doCopy(SVNCopyClient16.java:440)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnNgReposToReposCopy.run(SvnNgReposToReposCopy.java:65)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnNgReposToReposCopy.run(SvnNgReposToReposCopy.java:23)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1259)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnRemoteCopy.run(SvnRemoteCopy.java:227)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNCopyClient.doCopy(SVNCopyClient.java:581)
    at hudson.plugins.svn_tag.SvnTagPlugin.perform(SvnTagPlugin.java:182)
    at hudson.plugins.svn_tag.SvnTagPublisher.perform(SvnTagPublisher.java:79)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.cleanUp(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1064)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1785)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `svn: E160013: File not found` error does **not** linked to Jenkins, it's problem of your repository in common
2. Try to create tag by hand (repeate step-by-step Jenkins-job) and verify results
3. Check permissions of SVN-user, used by Jenkins (read trunk, write tags)

Comment: Thanks Lazy Badger can you elaborate some more information on this point
Try to create tag by hand (repeate step-by-step Jenkins-job) and verify results